# C++ Pointer to INT error?

Tags: c++, pointers, integer, codeblocks

Is there any method to use "cin" in c++ for a pointer to an INT? 
I mean

```
#include <iostream.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int *n = new int;
cout << "Insert n: ";
cin >> n;
cout << n;
return 0;
}
```

The compiler says no match for the operator ">>"

Thank you. :)

Comment: What would it mean to have the user provide pointer values?

Comment: Well...for example to change the values of memory where it points. I just can't figure it out how to make it with INT.

Comment: @Mihai _"Is there any method to use `cin` ..."_ Yes, dereference the pointer: `cin >> *n;`.

Comment: You can convert integral type (input) into pointers. If this gives a meaningful result is another question.

Comment: @Mihai: What does "use cin in c++ for a pointer to an INT" mean? What do you want/expect it to do? It is not possible to answer your question without knowing what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you cannot read a pointer from user input using `cin`. As your compiler says, there is no overload for such operation.

However, if your intention is to read an `int` and assign the value of the memory pointed by `n`, you can instead pass a reference to the `cin` operator by dereferencing the pointer: `cin >> *n`.

Comment: Thank you, thank you :) . You just saved my day. But how can I overwrite protected memory ?

Comment: @Mihai you shouldn't overwrite protected memory. It's protected for a reason. Your OS probably won't let you do that anyway. That seems like a separate question though, so you should create a new post for it.